# "errorType": "AttributeError", "errorMessage": "'ec2.instancesCollection' object has no attribute 'startup'"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am getting the below error:

```
"errorType": "AttributeError", "errorMessage": "'ec2.instancesCollection' object has no attribute 'startup'"
```

I have no idea why, I know that I am picking up the filter for certain.

The code looks correct to me. I have the exact same code but for starting up my instances and it works perfectly.

I was thinking it may be due to the "startup" part of the script but I am not sure.

The code:

```
#define connection
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Use the filter() method of the instances collection to retrieve
    # all shutdown EC2 instances.
    filters = [{
            'Name': 'tag:NightlyShutdown',
            'Values': ['True']
        },
        {
            'Name': 'instance-state-name', 
            'Values': ['stopped']
        }
    ]

    #filter the instances
    instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=filters)

    #locate all running instances
    DownInstances = [instance.id for instance in instances]

    #print the instances for logging purposes
    #print DownInstances 

    #make sure there are actually instances to start. 
    if len(DownInstances) > 0:
        #perform the shutdown
        startingUp = ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=DownInstances).startup()
        print StartingUp
    else:
        print "Nothing to see here"
```

Comment: start() not startup.

Comment: that was exactly it, thanks